# Minimal bootstrap css for buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a JSP component (jsp-tag), which should have a bootstrap look, 
because we use Bootstrap on some, not all pages. My component needs only
3 bootstrap classes for buttons (CSS classes .btn, .btn-success, .btn-error),
nothing else.

I would like to have that JSP component as self-contained as possible,
so I don't want to add the 100+KB bootstrap.css within my component, 
but only a minimal CSS. 
And another reason not to include the big bootstrap.css:
I don't want to change (=destroy) current pages with bootstrap styles.

Can I extract easily the styling for Bootstrap buttons somehow?

I copied and pasted the bootstrap stylings from my Firebug, which
works well on modern browsers (IE9+, FF, Chrome), but not on IE8.
So IE8 uses some CSS stylings that I could not reliably find out.

Comment: youre doin tha right, just inspect buttons with ie8 inspector ( f12 ) to see which styles are applied

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a custom bootstrap build for yourself via the bootstrap website.

Here's the [link](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/).

Just select the components you want and download the generated css file.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Although it gives me all buttons, not just the ones, that I wanted, but that's ok.

Comment: Great but this for Bootstrap 3, can you do the same thing for Bootstrap 4 i cant find the link

Comment: I am also searching for that. It seems to work differently in Bootstrap4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/